# How to properly display parsed data in table view after receiving them through completion handler

Tags: swift, networking, tableview, completionhandler

I need to show info about movies(taken from https://developers.themoviedb.org/) in tableView. I'm doing network request using a singleton and then pass parsed data to tableViewController through completion handler. I can print received data but I can't properly set them in tableView cell. Could you please help me how to fix this problem.

Network Manager

```
func getMovies(completion: @escaping ([Movies]?) -> Void) {
    
guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=\(apiKey)&language=en")
else { fatalError("Wrong URL") }
    
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    
     if let jsonData = data {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
     do {
        let moviesResult = try decoder.decode(MoviesResult.self, from: jsonData)
        let movies = moviesResult.results
        completion(movies)
        }
     catch {
            print(error)
          }
    }
}.resume()
```

}

Movies View Controller

```
var movies = [Movies]()
    
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   
        network.getMovies { result in
            if let result = result {
                self.movies = result
                print(self.movies)
            }
        }

extension MoviesViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return movies.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let movie = movies[indexPath.row]
        print(movie)
        
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "moviesMainInfo", for: indexPath) as? MovieTableViewCell {
            
            cell.filmTitle.text = movie.title
            cell.filmRating.text = String(movie.popularity!)
            return cell
          }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

**Parsed result**: [MovieApp.Movies(genreIDs: Optional([14, 28, 12]), overview: Optional("Wonder Woman comes into conflict with the Soviet Union during the Cold War in the 1980s and finds a formidable foe by the name of the Cheetah."), popularity: Optional(1927.057), title: Optional("Wonder Woman 1984"), releaseDate: Optional("2020-12-16"), posterPath: Optional("/8UlWHLMpgZm9bx6QYh0NFoq67TZ.jpg")),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything correctly, you just need to reload your `UITableView` when data arrives. Be aware that you need to reload your `UITableView` on the main thread, because `UIKit` isn't thread safe:

otherwise your application will most probably crash:

```
private func reloadTableView() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Also I encourage you to extract your networking function from `viewDidLoad`. An other improvement is to use `[weak self]` in your closures to avoid memory leaks:

```
private func loadData() {
    network.getMovies { [weak self] result in
        if let result = result {
            self?.movies = result
            print(self?.movies)
            self?.reloadTableView()
        } else {
            // Maybe show some info that the data could not be fetched
        }
    }
}
```

And in your `viewDidLoad` just call it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadData()
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for detailed explanation and recommendations about code! Now everything works :)

Comment: Try to read a bit about weak self: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html (a really good reference), totally worth it :)